# How to evaluate $ \int_0^1{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi x}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\mathrm dx} $ and get $ \frac{\mathrm i\pi \mathrm e}{2\cdot3\cdot4} $?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

The following definite integral identity holds

$$
\int_0^1{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi x}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\mathrm dx} = \frac{\mathrm i\pi \mathrm e}{2\cdot3\cdot4}
$$
and is easy to verify numerically. Mathematically, one can use the contour integral technique to obtain the analytic result. For example, one uses a standard contour traversing the branch cut $[0,1]$ back and forth and avoiding the endpoints by two tiny circles. Then residue theorem at infinity gives the result.

But is there a way to get the symbolic result using *Mathematica*? I tried the following one-liner but it did not work.

```
Integrate[E^(I Pi x) x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: So, how to evaluate it by contour integral?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Standard contour traversing the line segment back and forth and avoiding the singularities by two circles.

Comment: Maybe it‘s a good idea to show more details about this method in the post.

Comment: What would be the value of this post and its possible solution in a broader context? It's a sporadic integral and you already know the answer. One can invent many integrals computable by some method that MA cannot handle. More useful would be to consider a family of integrals so that people can learn how to evaluate. As for this one, I do not see how can it be computed by the contour integration.  If you provide more details, someone may try to implement it. But the question again is, why? Most probably it would be a synthetic approach, with only some steps done by MA. Is it your expectation?

Comment: This is of relevance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958624/prove-that-int-01-sin-pi-xxx1-x1-x-dx-frac-pi-e24 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226870/evaluating-an-integral-using-real-methods

Comment: And one more interesting link https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226875/proving-the-irrationality-of-pi-e-and-pi-e

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I said, only a synthetic approach is possible. Please, look [here](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Bestimmte_Integrale:_Form_R(x,sin)#0.5) (sec. **0.5**) for a mathematical proof of some of the transitions.

We have
$$
S=\int_0^1{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi x}x^x(1-x)^{1-x}\mathrm dx} =\int_0^1 (1-x)\, \exp\left\{\left[\mathrm i\pi+\log x-\log(1-x)\right]x\right\}\, \mathrm dx
$$

First we verify numerically

```
p[z_] := (1-z) E^((I π + Log[z] - Log[1 - z]) z)
N[Integrate[p[z], {z, 0, 1}] - (I π E)/24] // Chop
Out[1] = 0
```

Now we do a substitution

```
x[t_] := (E^t)/(E^t + 1)
p[x[t]] x'[t] // Simplify // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify
Out[2] = E^((t + E^t (I π + 2 t))/(1 + E^t))/(1 + E^t)^3
```

It leads us to the integral (please, notice mathematically identical, but slightly shorter form)
$$
S = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left\{(\mathrm i\pi + t)\, \frac{\mathrm e^t}{\mathrm e^t + 1}\right\}\, \frac{\mathrm e^t}{(\mathrm e^t + 1)^3}\, \mathrm dt
$$
The integrand has a single pole at $ t=-\mathrm i\pi $ encompassed by the red contour as indicated

[image]

Now we push the contour to infinity, whereupon integrals over the vertical tracks vanish. Now it is an easy matter (see the link) to reduce the desired integral to the value of residue at $-\mathrm i\pi$.

$$
S = -\pi\,\mathrm i\, \mathrm{Res}_{t=-\mathrm i\pi}\left[ \exp\left\{(\mathrm i\pi + t)\, \frac{\mathrm e^t}{\mathrm e^t + 1}\right\}\, \frac{\mathrm e^t}{(\mathrm e^t + 1)^3}\right].
$$

The final result can be obtained as follows

```
-π I Residue[%, {t, -I π}]
Out[3] = (1/24) I E π
```

---

The figure generating code was requested and is presented below. Notice, it derives from some of the posts here. Newer version of MA has [`ComplexPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html).

```
Clear[complexPlot]
complexPlot[zf_,xMin_,xMax_,yMin_,yMax_]:=Module[{x,y,h,f},
 f[x_,y_]:={Rescale[Arg[zf[x+I y]],{-Pi,Pi}],Abs[zf[x+I y]],1};
 Graphics[{},PlotRange->{{xMin,xMax},{yMin,yMax}},FrameTicks->{{Table[k π,{k,-5,5}],Table[k π,{k,-5,5}]},{Automatic,Automatic}},
 Epilog->{Inset[Show[ColorCombine[Table[
   Print[i];
   im[i]=ImageTake[Image[DensityPlot[f[x,y][[i]],{x,xMin,xMax},{y,yMin,yMax},
   Frame->None,ImageMargins->0,PlotPoints->60,AspectRatio->Automatic,MaxRecursion->3,
   PlotRangePadding->None,ColorFunction->GrayLevel,ColorFunctionScaling->None,Exclusions->None,PlotRange->Full],ColorSpace->"Grayscale",ImageSize-> 1200],{1,-2},{1,-2}],{i,3}],"HSB"],AspectRatio->Full],
{xMin,yMin},{0,0},{xMax-xMin,yMax-yMin}],
Inset[
Print[4];
ContourPlot[Abs[zf[x+I y]],{x,xMin,xMax},{y,yMin,yMax},PlotPoints->30,AspectRatio->Automatic,MaxRecursion->6,ContourShading->None,Frame->None,ImageMargins->0,PlotRangePadding->None,Contours->6,Exclusions->None,ContourStyle->Directive[Thin,Black],Axes->True,Ticks->None,AxesStyle->Dashed],
{0,0},{0,0},{xMax-xMin,yMax-yMin}],
EdgeForm[Red],FaceForm[None], Rectangle[{-9,-2π},{9,0}]
},
Frame->True,PlotRangePadding->.08]
]

Clear[f]
f[t_]:=E^((t+E^t (I π+2 t))/(1+E^t))/(1+E^t)^3

complexPlot[f,-10,10,-15,15]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it.

Comment: Could you please share the code generating the figure?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Please, see updates.

Comment: What function is `g` in `complexPlot[g,-10,10,-15,15]` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you, corrected now!

Comment: Why is it $ \mathrm i\pi + t $ rather than $ \mathrm i\pi + 2t $ in the formulae?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Yes, I saw your edit. There was a tiny mistake in your edit, therefore I reverted. The current version is equivalent to the expression generated by MA, but slightly shorter. See, `f[t_]:=E^((t+E^t (I π+2 t))/(1+E^t))/(1+E^t)^3` and `g[t_]:=E^((E^t (I π+t))/(1+E^t))/(1+E^t)^3 E^t` are equivalent `Simplify[f[t]-g[t]]`

Comment: From version 12 you can use the built in function `ComplexPlot[f[t], {t, -10 - 5 π I, 10 + 5 π I},ColorFunction -> "ShiftedCyclicLogAbs",PlotLegends -> Automatic]`  to get [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E2a5A.png).

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Comment: As you have mentioned in the comment, can this integral be generalized to one containing one or more parameters?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Yes, a very interesting generalization would be $\int_0^1 x^n\sin\left(\pi x\right)x^x\left(1-x\right)^{1-x}\,dx = b_{n+2}\pi e.$ This appears here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958624/prove-that-int-01-sin-pi-xxx1-x1-x-dx-frac-pi-e24 (2nd answer). Yet another unsolved problem is to compute the integral without substitution, but rather by the residue at infinity, or equivalently at $z=0$ of $1/z^2f(1/z)$. I tried this approach, but MA is unable to compute this residue. It might be an interesting question though, there are not so many posts about residues.

Answer (score 2):

The following does not answer the OP's question but does supply the answer to a few comments asked above:

Rather than just a comment that might be missed, I am posting the links I've received from the Mathematics forum.  I was interested in the integral and felt asking it's solution was more appropriate there: It's a beautiful example of using the residue at infinity.
Here's my question (so as to give credit to those who helped me):  [My question about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339311/can-contour-integration-be-used-to-integrate-uu1-u1-u)

Here's the link @metamorphy supplied which basically answers the question of how to integrate it:  [Post of a related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958624/prove-that-int-01-sin-pi-xxx1-x1-x-dx-frac-pi-e24)

And here's the link to Wikipedia that describes the process:  [Example 6 in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration)

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to Integrate it analytically (tried `Integrate[E^(I Pi x) x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x), x, Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]` without success).

I had to use `NIntegrate`

```
NIntegrate[E^(I Pi x) x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]
(* 1.73472*10^-17 + 0.355822 I *)
```

and to get rid of the small Real portion

```
Chop[NIntegrate[E^(I Pi x) x^x (1 - x)^(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]]
(* 0. + 0.355822 I *)
```

gives the same answer as your analytic answer

```
N[(I Pi E)/(2*3*4)]
(* 0. + 0.355822 I *)
```

Comment: I am afraid this might not be a suitable answer to the question.